# Prove Statement with Asymptotic Notation

Tags: algorithms, induction, asymptotics, data-structure

The questions is to prove or disprove 
$n!=O(n^n)$
Using the definitions of big O, I consider:
$n!<=n^n$
Using induction I get: 
$P(1): 1<=1$ 
$P(k+1): (k+1)!<=(k+1)^{k+1}$

Then moving things around I end up with the left side as:
$k(k+1)^{k+1}$
But I'm not sure that's correct. Is this correct and if not what do I do with the final step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do induction (or, at least, not as explicitly). Instead, you could note that $n!$ and $n^n$ are both the product of $n$ positive numbers, and in one of the products, all the factors are larger than in the other one.

Alternatively, $n!$ and $n^n$ both count the number of words of length $n$ you can make using an alphabet consisting of $n$ symbols, but one of them has the additional restriction that you must use each symbol exactly once.

If you want to do it the induction way, consider the following:
$$
(k+1)^{k+1} = (k+1)(k+1)^k\geq (k+1)k^k \geq (k+1)\cdot k! = (k+1)!
$$

All of these three approaches prove that $n!\leq n^n$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: So you're saying essentially plug in numbers and noting the relationship?  I guess I'm having trouble seeing how that can be used as a proof. The induction makes more sense to me. Why did you start with the right side instead of the left?

Comment: @NikNik Yes, that is what I'm saying, although you make it sound like you have to do it for each $n$. And there is no real reason why I wrote the inequality in that order except that I happened to start with $(k+1)^{k+1}$ and just kept going from there.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just say $1\le n$, $2\le n$, ..., $n\le n$, and then multiply left- and right-hand sides to get $n!\le n^n = Mn^n$ for $M=1$ and all $n\in\mathbb N$, thus proving $n!=O(n^n)$.